# ARD ZDF Deutschlandradio - deregistration

Tags: germany, fees, radio

I am a student and I am going to complete my studies this April and I will go back to India permanently. I live in a shared WG and we are paying the [ARD ZDF Deutschlandradio Beitragsservice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beitragsservice_von_ARD,_ZDF_und_Deutschlandradio) fee from my reference number. I want to de-register from ARD. I will de-register from the city hall by mid of April as I will leave by end of April to India.

What is the procedure to de-register from ARD. Can anyone please guide me through the same?

Will a flight ticket to India suffice as proof that I am moving out of Germany? Or what else is required? I will not be here from 1st of May. I guess I have to move out from Germany within 15 days of my de-registration from the city office. So, I don't know if that period is sufficient to de-register from ARD.

Comment: Last time I checked, courts were still working out whether the new GEZ system is legal at all. Moreover, this is rather about bureaucratic procedure than law. It is probably better asked on [expats.se]. That being said, I suggest that you just send them a formless letter that you are leaving the country stop paying them. Let them worry about everything else.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Last time I checked every single court case so far has been ruled in favor of the new system – I don't know where you got the idea from. Sometimes public employees make mistake when collecting the fees and some lower courts have therefore ruled in favor of individual contributors. But that has nothing to do with whether the *system is legal at all*.

Comment: You send them [that form](https://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/e175/e183/Buergerinnen_und_Buerger_Wohnungsabmeldung_0106.pdf) to deregister.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called up the ARD customer care and they said we can just call them and tell them when we are leaving the country and they will automatically de-register us from that month. I guess they will cross check with the city de-registration details.

Answer (score 4):

Even though as you found out calling is also sufficient, there is also a form available for this:

[Abmeldung der Wohnung/en](https://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/e175/e183/Buergerinnen_und_Buerger_Wohnungsabmeldung_0106.pdf)

One of the reasons listed is

> Ich ziehe dauerhaft ins Ausland

(I am moving abroad)

They ask for a

> Meldeamtliche Bescheinigung

for this case. That's the deregistration notice.

Answer (score 3):

probably, now it can be done online via : https://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/buergerinnen_und_buerger/formulare/abmelden/index_ger.html